# How do I script Powerpoint to save a directory of PPTX files as PDFs?

Tags: script, ms-office

If I have a directory of PPTX files I would like to save as PDFs.  How do I script this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have PowerPoint installed, this is quite simple using Automator.

(I have Office 2011, so I'm unsure if this would work with 2008)

Start Automator, and create a new Folder Action, and choose the input folder (i.e.: the one containing the PPTX files)

From the Actions list, choose "Convert Format of PowerPoint Presentations".  For the "New Format" option, choose "Portable Document Format".

Save it & close Automator, and you're done!

Any PPTX files saved in the chosen folder (either pre-existing, or any new ones you save from now on) will automatically be converted to PDF as an additional copy.

Hope this helps!

-U

Comment: That pretty much worked.  I'm new to Automator so it took me a while to figure it out.  I had to save the Automator action as an Application and drop the PPTX files onto it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AppleScript to convert PowerPoint files to PDF documents, as described in my answer to a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406988/57019):

1. Open Script Editor, select New Document and paste the script below. Make sure you adapt parts that are locale specific like "Sichern", "Vorschau" and the like to your local language ... and check for the latest version at https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/ppt2pdf

   ```
   on run (argv)
       log (count (argv))
       if ((count of argv) < 2) then
           log "usage: ppt2pdf basepath [filenames]"
       else
           my ppt2Pdf(argv)
       end if
   end run

   --
   -- convert PowerPoint to PDF on the given list of files
   --
   on ppt2Pdf(fileNames)
       log "launching Powerpoint ..."
       set pp to "Microsoft PowerPoint"
       tell application pp -- work on version 15.15 or newer
           launch
           set isfirst to true
           repeat with fileName in fileNames
               if isfirst then
                   set basepath to fileName
                   log "base path is " & basepath
                   set isfirst to false
               else
                   if fileName ends with ".ppt" or fileName ends with ".pptx" or fileName ends with ".pptm" then
                       set filePath to basepath & "/" & fileName
                       -- set filePath to POSIX path of fileAlias
                       set pdfPath to my makeNewPath(filePath)
                       log "trying to convert powerpoint file " & filePath & " to " & pdfPath
                       open filePath

                       -- save active presentation in pdfPath as save as PDF 
                       -- save in same folder
                       -- https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=26342
                       --tell application "System Events"
                       --  set listOfProcesses to (name of every process where background only is false)
                       --  tell me to set selectedProcesses to choose from list listOfProcesses with multiple selections allowed
                       --end tell
                       --repeat with processName in selectedProcesses
                       --  log processName
                       --end repeat

                       if not my chooseMenuItem(pp, "Datei", "Drucken...") then
                           error number -128
                       end if

                       --my showUiElements(pp, "menu button")
                       -- my waitFor(button whose description is "PDF", 5, 0.5)
                       my choosePopUp(pp, "Layout für den Druck", "Notizen")
                       my choosePopUp(pp, "Farbausgabeformat", "Farbe")
                       --my chooseMenuButtonItem(pp, "PDF", "Als PDF sichern")
                       local myTitle
                       tell application "System Events"
                           -- the magic of Applescript
                           -- if you really want the title and not a reference to it you need to use an operator
                           -- http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/applescriptdefinitiveguide/applescpttdg2-CHP-12-SECT-5.html
                           set myTitle to title of window 1 of process pp & ""
                       end tell
                       my chooseMenuButtonItem(pp, "PDF", "In Vorschau öffnen")
                       delay 5
                       tell application "System Events"
                           log "waiting for Vorschau to display " & myTitle
                           set timeLeft to my waitForAppearWindow(myTitle, process "Vorschau", 30, 0.5)
                           if timeLeft < 0 then
                               log "Vorschau " & myTitle & " window didn't show up after 30 secs"
                               error number -128
                           else
                               log "Vorschau appeared with " & timeLeft & "secs left"
                               tell process "Vorschau"
                                   delay 0.2
                                   click menu item "Als PDF exportieren …" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Ablage" of menu bar 1
                                   delay 0.5
                                   -- CMD-SHIFT-G to set the export director
                                   -- https://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/keycodes.php
                                   keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
                                   delay 0.2

                                   tell sheet 1 of window (myTitle)
                                       tell sheet 1
                                           -- dereference basePath
                                           local basePathStr
                                           set basePathStr to basepath & ""
                                           set value of first combo box to basePathStr
                                           delay 0.2
                                           click button "Öffnen"
                                           delay 0.2
                                       end tell
                                       click button "Sichern"
                                       set timeLeft to my waitForAppear(sheet 1, 3, 0.2)
                                       tell sheet 1
                                           if timeLeft > 0 then
                                               click button "Ersetzen"
                                           end if
                                       end tell
                                       delay 5
                                       keystroke "q" using {command down}
                                   end tell

                               end tell
                           end if
                       end tell

                       --tell application "System Events"
                       --  set timeLeft to my waitForAppear("button", button "Sichern" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp, 5, 0.5)
                       --  if timeLeft < 0 then
                       --      log "Sichern button didn't show up after 5 secs"
                       --      error number -128
                       --  end if
                       --  click button "Sichern" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp
                       --end tell

                       --tell application "System Events"
                       --  delay 0.5
                       --  try
                       --      set timeLeft to my waitForAppear("button", button "Ersetzen" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp, 5, 0.5)
                       --      if timeLeft < 0 then
                       --          log "Ersetzen button didn't show up after 5 secs"
                       --          error number -128
                       --      end if
                       --      click button "Ersetzen" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp
                       --  end try
                       --end tell
                       log "done ..."
                       -- close filePath
                   end if
               end if
           end repeat
           -- still in tell powerpoint context
           --tell application "System Events"
           --  delay 0.5
           --  try
           --      set timeLeft to my waitForVanish("window", window "Sichern" of process pp, 60, 1)
           --      if timeLeft < 0 then
           --          log "print dialog didn't vanish after 60 secs"
           --          error number -128
           --      end if
           --  end try
           --end tell
           quit
       end tell
   end ppt2Pdf

   on showElement(uiElem)
       local className
       set className to class of uiElem as string
       log (((«class pDSC» of uiElem as string) & "=" & value of uiElem as string) & "(" & className) & ")"
   end showElement

   --
   -- show all UI elements
   --
   on showUiElements(appName, filterClassName)
       tell application "System Events"
           tell process appName
               tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
                   repeat with uiElem in entire contents of it as list
                       try
                           local className
                           set className to class of uiElem as string
                           if filterClassName is missing value or className is filterClasssname then
                               log (((description of uiElem as string) & "=" & value of uiElem as string) & "(" & className) & ")"
                           end if
                       end try
                   end repeat
               end tell
           end tell
       end tell
   end showUiElements

   --
   -- wait for the given element to appear
   --
   on waitForAppearWindow(elementName, parentElement, time, slice)
       set timeLeft to time
       set appeared to false
       repeat until (appeared) or timeLeft ≤ 0
           try
               set appeared to window elementName of parentElement exists
           end try
           delay slice
           log "."
           set timeLeft to timeLeft - slice
       end repeat
       log timeLeft
       return timeLeft
   end waitForAppearWindow

   --
   -- wait for the given element to appear
   --
   on waitForAppear(element, time, slice)
       set timeLeft to time
       set appeared to false
       repeat until (appeared) or timeLeft ≤ 0
           try
               set appeared to element exists
           end try
           delay slice
           log "."
           set timeLeft to timeLeft - slice
       end repeat
       log timeLeft
       return timeLeft
   end waitForAppear

   ---
   --- wait for the given element to vanish
   ---
   on waitForVanish(element, time, slice)
       set timeLeft to time
       try
           repeat while (exists element) and timeLeft > 0
               delay slice
               log "."
               set timeLeft to timeLeft - slice
           end repeat
       end try
       log timeLeft
       return timeLeft
   end waitForVanish


   on chooseMenuButtonItem(appName, buttonName, itemName)
       tell application "System Events"
           tell process appName
               tell window 1
                   local win1
                   set win1 to it
                   tell sheet 1
                       log "choosing " & itemName & " of menu button " & buttonName
                       tell menu button buttonName
                           click
                           delay 0.1
                           tell menu 1
                               click menu item itemName
                           end tell
                       end tell
                   end tell
               end tell
           end tell
       end tell
   end chooseMenuButtonItem
   --
   -- choose a popup 
   --
   on choosePopUp(appName, buttonName, itemName)
       tell application "System Events"
           tell process appName
               tell window 1
                   tell sheet 1
                       log "choosing " & itemName & " of pop up menu " & buttonName
                       --repeat with pbutton in pop up buttons
                       --  local pbutton1
                       --  set pbutton1 to pbutton
                       --  log description of pbutton & "=" & value of pbutton
                       --end repeat
                       tell (1st pop up button whose description is buttonName)
                           click it
                           delay 0.5
                           pick menu item itemName of menu 1
                       end tell
                   end tell
               end tell
           end tell
       end tell
   end choosePopUp

   --
   -- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/
   -- LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide
   -- AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW17
   --
   on chooseMenuItem(theAppName, theMenuName, theMenuItemName)
       try
           -- Bring the target app to the front
           tell application theAppName
               activate
           end tell

           -- Target the app
           tell application "System Events"
               tell process theAppName

                   -- Target the menu bar
                   tell menu bar 1

                       -- Target the menu by name
                       tell menu bar item theMenuName
                           tell menu theMenuName

                               -- Click the menu item
                               log "clicking " & theMenuItemName
                               click menu item theMenuItemName
                           end tell
                       end tell
                   end tell
               end tell
           end tell
           return true
       on error
           return false
       end try
   end chooseMenuItem



   on makeNewPath(f)
       set t to f as string
       if t ends with ".pptx" or t ends with ".pptm" then
           return (text 1 thru -5 of t) & "pdf"
       else
           return (text 1 thru -4 of t) & "pdf"
       end if
   end makeNewPath
   ```
2. Save the file as `ppt2pdf.scpt`, for example to a subfolder named `bin`  in your home directory.
3. Open TextEdit and paste this (correct the path to `ppt2pdf.scpt` as necessary):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # use current path as base path
   osascript $HOME/bin/ppt2pdf.scpt $(pwd) $@
   ```

   (In the code above, `$HOME` is a shell variable that points to your home directory.)
4. Save the file as `ppt2pdf`, for example to `$HOME/bin`.
5. make it executable with

   ```
   chmod +x $HOME/bin/ppt2pdf
   ```

Now, to convert PowerPoint files to PDF documents, open Terminal, change directory to the folder where the PowerPoint files are located, and run:

```
$HOME/bin/ppt2pdf *.pptx
```

or just

```
ppt2pdf *.pptx
```

if your $HOME/bin directory is part of your $PATH