# How do I get Outlook actions to be available in the Automator Library tree?

Tags: macos, ms-office, automator

OS X El Cap 10.11.6

Outlook for Mac 15.39

I'm filtering the Library with the string "outlook" and there are no actions available. Is there something I can do to get Outlook items to show up in here?

[image: Automator screenshot]

Comment: IIRC Microsoft discontinued Automator support after Office 2011 for Mac.

Comment: Different question, similar answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217004/how-do-i-get-automator-actions-for-microsoft-powerpoint-and-word