# applescript gives compile error on ui elements with blank in name like "ui elements" "pop up button"

Tags: applescript

When trying to do some UI scripting with applescript I found quite a few examples that use e.g.

```
pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of window "somewindow" of application process "someprocess"
```

I am now using the wonderful Late Night Software Script debugger to find out why i can't use such statements.
I e.g. get an error message:
[image: Screenshot of compile error]

when trying to use the statement:

```
set bname to  description of pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of win
```

without a nested tell context.

only if i comment out this line the rest of the code compiles.

**What is going on here ?**

**How can the cut&paste style of nested tell commands be avoided?**

I am on Mac OS 10.13.6 High Sierra using ScriptDebugger 7.0.12. And script Editor 2.10 / Applescript 2.7
[image: ScreenShot of AppleScript version]

```
--
-- show all UI elements
--
on showUiElements(appName)
    local win
    set win to my getWindow(appName)
    log name of win
    
    --set bname to  description of pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of win
end showUiElements

on getWindow(appName)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process appName
            set win to 1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true
            ---log "getting windowTitle name=" & name & "description=" & description
            return win
        end tell
    end tell
end getWindow
```

Working code - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406986/57019 for a more recent version ...

```
-- 2018-01-31
-- https://github.com/irmowan/Convert-ppt-to-pdf/blob/master/Convert-ppt-to-pdf.applescript
-- modified by WF 2020-11-15
-- 
-- ppt2Pdf({"/Users/wf/Projekte/2009/CPSAMaterial2009/Folien", "CA02-GrundbegriffeI-RundUmSoftware.pptx"})

--http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050523140439734
-- passing command line arguments to applescript
on run (argv)
    -- log (count (argv))
    if ((count of argv) < 2) then
        log "usage: ppt2pdf basepath [filenames]"
    else
        my ppt2Pdf(argv)
    end if
end run

--
-- convert powerpoint to pdf on the given list of files
--
on ppt2Pdf(fileNames)
    log "launching Powerpoint ..."
    set pp to "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    tell application pp -- work on version 15.15 or newer
        launch
        set isfirst to true
        repeat with fileName in fileNames
            if isfirst then
                set basepath to fileName
                log "base path is " & basepath
                set isfirst to false
            else
                if fileName ends with ".ppt" or fileName ends with ".pptx" or fileName ends with ".pptm" then
                    set filePath to basepath & "/" & fileName
                    -- set filePath to POSIX path of fileAlias
                    set pdfPath to my makeNewPath(filePath)
                    log "trying to convert powerpoint file " & filePath & " to " & pdfPath
                    open filePath
                    
                    -- save active presentation in pdfPath as save as PDF 
                    -- save in same folder
                    -- https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=26342
                    --tell application "System Events"
                    --  set listOfProcesses to (name of every process where background only is false)
                    --  tell me to set selectedProcesses to choose from list listOfProcesses with multiple selections allowed
                    --end tell
                    --repeat with processName in selectedProcesses
                    --  log processName
                    --end repeat
                    
                    if not my chooseMenuItem(pp, "Datei", "Drucken...") then
                        error number -128
                    end if
                    
                    --my showUiElements(pp, "menu button")
                    -- my waitFor(button whose description is "PDF", 5, 0.5)
                    my choosePopUp(pp, "Layout für den Druck", "Notizen")
                    my choosePopUp(pp, "Farbausgabeformat", "Farbe")
                    my chooseMenuButtonItem(pp, "PDF", "Als PDF sichern")
                    tell application "System Events"
                        set timeLeft to my waitFor("button", button "Sichern" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp, 5, 0.5)
                        if timeLeft < 0 then
                            log "Sichern button didn't show up after 5 secs"
                            error number -128
                        end if
                        click button "Sichern" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp
                    end tell
                    tell application "System Events"
                        set timeLeft to my waitFor("button", button "Ersetzen" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp, 5, 0.5)
                        if timeLeft < 0 then
                            log "Ersetzen button didn't show up after 5 secs"
                            error number -128
                        end if
                        click button "Ersetzen" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process pp
                        
                    end tell
                    
                    log "done ..."
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    tell application pp -- work on version 15.15 or newer
        quit
    end tell
end ppt2Pdf

on showElement(uiElem)
    local className
    set className to class of uiElem as string
    log (((description of uiElem as string) & "=" & value of uiElem as string) & "(" & className) & ")"
end showElement

--
-- show all UI elements
--
on showUiElements(appName, filterClassName)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process appName
            tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
                repeat with uiElem in entire contents of it as list
                    try
                        local className
                        set className to class of uiElem as string
                        if filterClassName is missing value or className is filterClasssname then
                            log (((description of uiElem as string) & "=" & value of uiElem as string) & "(" & className) & ")"
                        end if
                    end try
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end showUiElements


--
-- wait for the given element
--
on waitFor(elementClass, element, time, slice)
    set timeLeft to time
    repeat while not (exists element) and timeLeft > 0
        delay slice
        log "."
        set timeLeft to timeLeft - slice
    end repeat
    log timeLeft
    return timeLeft
end waitFor

on chooseMenuButtonItem(appName, buttonName, itemName)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process appName
            tell window 1
                local win1
                set win1 to it
                tell sheet 1
                    log "choosing " & itemName & " of menu button " & buttonName
                    tell menu button buttonName
                        click
                        delay 0.1
                        tell menu 1
                            click menu item itemName
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end chooseMenuButtonItem
--
-- choose a popup 
--
on choosePopUp(appName, buttonName, itemName)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process appName
            tell window 1
                tell sheet 1
                    log "choosing " & itemName & " of pop up menu " & buttonName
                    --repeat with pbutton in pop up buttons
                    --  local pbutton1
                    --  set pbutton1 to pbutton
                    --  log description of pbutton & "=" & value of pbutton
                    --end repeat
                    tell (1st pop up button whose description is buttonName)
                        click it
                        delay 0.5
                        pick menu item itemName of menu 1
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end choosePopUp

--
-- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/
-- LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide
-- AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW17
--
on chooseMenuItem(theAppName, theMenuName, theMenuItemName)
    try
        -- Bring the target app to the front
        tell application theAppName
            activate
        end tell
        
        -- Target the app
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process theAppName
                
                -- Target the menu bar
                tell menu bar 1
                    
                    -- Target the menu by name
                    tell menu bar item theMenuName
                        tell menu theMenuName
                            
                            -- Click the menu item
                            log "clicking " & theMenuItemName
                            click menu item theMenuItemName
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end chooseMenuItem



on makeNewPath(f)
    set t to f as string
    if t ends with ".pptx" or t ends with ".pptm" then
        return (text 1 thru -5 of t) & "pdf"
    else
        return (text 1 thru -4 of t) & "pdf"
    end if
end makeNewPath
```

Comment: It would be so much better if you would actually provide _code_ that can be literally copied and pasted into **Script Editor** pointing to a default **Apple** installed _application_ and its state to test against. As currently posted, not sure what you expect we should do with your _code_ to test it. That said, `set bname to description of pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of win` needs to be wrapped in a `tell` _block_ of an _application_ that understands it, e.g., **System Events**. However, you should also use `try` and `on error` _statements_ to trap and handle _errors_ as well.

Comment: Please find the full code now above. I am just wondering how the code could be written "cleaner". I was trying to avoid the redundant nesting of tells and don't know how to avoid it. The approach i tried first leads to the compile error.

Comment: As your _code_ is targeting a non-default **Apple** installed _application_ , namely **Microsoft PowerPoint**, sorry I do not have that _application_ and will look no further at this question. Hopefully someone who has **Microsoft PowerPoint** and understands **AppleScript** too will come along and help.

Comment: thx for looking into this - if i find time I'll create a different example to explain the problem. For the time being i needs this script to work which it somewhat does in the cut&paste style.

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406986/57019 for the above scripts latest version